# Reconsider historical lock on hardware recommendations

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, locked-question

Some of our older questions are about hardware recommendations.  Well, Hardware Recommendations.SE is now live - lets clear up some confusion.

No, I'm not suggesting migrating these questions there, but properly and finally removing them from here.

In particular, I am looking at [What are good keyboards for programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2254/what-are-good-keyboards-for-programming).

> Programmers tend to type a lot of code, bashing a lot of shortcuts and a lot of other things.
>
> What keyboards are good for programming?

This is a broadly unfocused question with 33 answers.  Many not more than a picture, others just saying they wished they had a keyboard that cost several thousand dollars.  This post is no more valuable (and out of date, that wonderfully expensive keyboard hasn't been in production for years) than going to [amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/?keywords=keyboards) and browsing the reviews there.

If it has merit, reask the question on HardwareRec.SE with the appropriate constraints to scope - but it is not now nor has ever been a good question on Programmers.SE and its historical significance is very much in doubt.

Comment: I agree, that post needs to turn a pretty shade of crimson.

Comment: Burn it!  Burn it with fire!

Comment: [status-deleted]